# Why does my Panel cut the text strangely off?

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment, panel

I have the problem that the text inside my panel gets cut of strangely. The panel is located inside a textbox. But even if I replace the textbox by a flowlayoutpanel, I have the same issue.

**Code:**

```
List<string> list = datenbank.FerienAuswahl(monat, jahr);

        int i = 0;
        //Create Panel

        try
        {
            //Fill Panel
            do
            {
                Label panel = new Label();
                panel.Name = "panel" + i;
                panel.Height = 30;
                panel.Width = 400;
                panel.AutoSize = false;
                panel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                panel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                panel.Text = list[i];
                Label ferien = new Label();
                panel.Controls.Add(ferien);
                tbFerien.Controls.Add(panel);
                i++;
            } while (i < list.Count);
        }
        catch { }
```

**Result:**

[image]

I have already tried to change the width of the panel. But as result I only get a messed up alignment of the text.
**The only settings of the textbox I have changed are these:**

Multiline: True

TextAlign: Center

Size: 359; 125

Does Someone know what else I could try ?

Comment: It's "Ferien" not "ferien" ;)

Comment: haha, nice one ;)

Comment: Bitte kein so wirren Bezeichnungen! Panel != Label!

Comment: @TaW Ja ich weiss... Das Projekt ist nicht kommerziell. Demzufolge wird hier also keine Verwirrung aufkommen ;) Sollten mehrere Leute damit arbeiten, würde ich dies Natürlich nicht so schreiben.

Comment: Naja, wir hier sind schon mal verwirrt, und, wenn ich darf, schließe ich dich mal einfach mit ein ;-)

Comment: @TaW haha hat mir gerade zu denken gegeben :) Habe es umbenennt für künftige Fragen ;)

Comment: Good. And do believe an old man: The most important reader of your code is your own future self!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines worry me:

```
Label panel = new Label();
Label ferien = new Label();
panel.Controls.Add(ferien);
tbFerien.Controls.Add(panel);
```

It seems to me you are adding one label to another. That's not good. Use a `Panel` or `TableLayoutPanel` instead of the actual panel and make sure you have your positioning good.

Comment: What a mistake from my side xD I just had to delete the Label "panel"... Now it works fine again. Thanks

Comment: Wonderful. Glad it helped.